# Custom badge using PPBadgeView not showing in navigationitem - swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uinavigationcontroller, badge

I am creating an app i want to show badge icon when there an notification to alert for user.

I have found out library named `PPBadgeView` and i have followed the following instruction which i am using `pod 'PPBadgeViewSwift'` and then `pod install`

In programming i want to implement rightNavigationBar with the badgeview but it doesn't show me.

What i have done:

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "notification")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(notificationHandle))

rightBarButton.pp.addBadge(text: "99+")
rightBarButton.pp.moveBadge(x: -5, y: 0)
rightBarButton.pp.setBadge(height: 12)
rightBarButton.pp.setBadge(flexMode: PPBadgeViewFlexMode.tail)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton
```

When i run the app i just see the icon that i have set only. I don't know where is my badgeView.

Comment: PPBadgeViewSwift they are not provided image api for UIBarButtonItem.You can try like this way for getting badgeView. let rightBarButton  = UIBarButtonItem.init(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(notificationHandle))

Comment: This will be sad if i want to custom image for UIBarbuttonItem

Comment: check below link it might be useful https://github.com/mikeMTOL/UIBarButtonItem-Badge

Comment: For swift https://github.com/JaleelNazir/MJBadgeButtonSwift

Answer (score 1):

If you are using iOS 11+ you have to async the task

```
let rightBarButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "notification")?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(notificationHandle))
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarButton

if (UIDevice.current.systemVersion as NSString).doubleValue >= 11.0 {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.01, execute: {
        rightBarButton.pp.addBadge(text: "99+")
        rightBarButton.pp.moveBadge(x: -5, y: 0)
        rightBarButton.pp.setBadge(height: 12)
        rightBarButton.pp.setBadge(flexMode: PPBadgeViewFlexMode.tail)
    })
} else {
    rightBarButton.pp.addBadge(text: "99+")
    rightBarButton.pp.moveBadge(x: -5, y: 0)
    rightBarButton.pp.setBadge(height: 12)
    rightBarButton.pp.setBadge(flexMode: PPBadgeViewFlexMode.tail)
}
```

Comment: This is great! But can you tell why do we have to async the task?

Comment: in iOS 11+ you can't reach `UIBarButtonItem` views in the main thread of `viewDidLoad()` that's why you have processing the task asynchronous